# How to throw same exception thrown by external endpoint in springboot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, exception

I'm accessing an external api and I'm expecting to get an image as response (`byte[]`). My method that connects to this endpoint looks like this:

```
 private byte[] retrieveImage(String uri) {
     byte[] imageBytes = null;
     try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(url);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ImageNotReadException(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return imageBytes;
    }
```

It turned out that if I pass the wrong parameters to the target endpoint I get this error message:
[image]

So basically I would like to `throw` the same error above but I also would like to `throw` an `ImageNotReadException` (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!` ) in case the program fails to read the image (`byte[]`). So basically, my method  `private byte[] retrieveImage(String uri)` would have to throw my read image exception and the endpoint response exception.

Any tips?
Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you want to throw the same exception, just put : throw  ex;

Comment: How can I do that? It's an external api and it returns an image (byte[]) if everything is fine, if there's error it returns {"error": {"code":400, :"Invalid 'layersDefs'", "details":[]}}. Don't know how to handle this.

Comment: your question is not clear! where do you want to handle the response? in your java code or on browser?

Comment: I thought my question was clear. Anyway, what I want is a way of throwing the same exception it's thrown by the endpoint which is :"{"error": {"code":400, :"Invalid 'layersDefs'", "details":[]}}." when there's an error. The problem is that the endpoing will return an image (byte[]) if everything is fine or the error "{"error": {"code":400, :"Invalid 'layersDefs'", "details":[]}}." if there's an error. In my code

Comment: I already handle an exception in case I can't read the image (byte[]), but don't know how to handle a response where it can return byte[] in case everything is fine or "{"error": {"code":400, :"Invalid 'layersDefs'", "details":[]}}." in case there's an error. Any tips? Don't know if it's clear now, if not let me know and will try to be more clear.

Comment: You're "catching" an HTTP Response code and wanting to throw an internal error, or return the same response to the client of your service?  Again, rather unclear what you want to do.  Assuming you want to parse non-200 response codes and pass them along - which in general is not the best approach - you'd do exactly that: take the response from your call to the external system, check if it was a success (2xx) and, if not, use it as your own Response object.  Done.

Comment: @sofend thanks mate for the insight. Sorry if the message was unclear, english is not my first language, so trying to be more clear as possible.  The endpoint that I'm hitting can return an image or an http response json error. So if theres an error I would like to return the same http response error json coming from the endpoint. Apart from that I still wanna to return an error in case my internal program cannot read the bytes[] from the endpoint I'm hitting. So basically, I would like to return the same http error coming from the endpoint in case there's an error and also

Comment: my error when reading the byte[] from the image (ImageNotReadException)

Comment: If your client is flexible to change the return type, you can easily change the return type for a custom object type with a status code and byte[] as properties (ex:Response) and then return it as relevant. Or You can change the method signature to throw your own Exception and you can throw that explicitly when the external api return the error.

Comment: Thanks @sampathpremarathna for the reply. Yes, my client is flexible. Will do that. Cheers mate

Comment: If you want to help, you should add a real example, I don't see that you are calling an external API

Comment: @JonathanJohx the following lines are calling the api:                                   
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(uri); where "uri" is the external endpoint. In that situation I'm expecting an image as response. That's why I'm using BufferedImage. But I also can have a response like this: {"error": {"code":400, :"Invalid 'layersDefs'", "details":[]}}. That's why I would like to know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have commented see below options

```
private Response retrieveImage(String uri) {
     byte[] imageBytes = null;
Response r=new Response();
     try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(url);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
            imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            r.setImage(imageBytes);
            r.setStatus(1);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            r.setStatus(0);
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Response :

```
class Response{ 
String status;
byte[] image;

//getters setters
}
```

Or :

```
  private Response retrieveImage(String uri)throws CustomException {
         byte[] imageBytes = null;
         try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(url);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
                imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new CustomException(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return imageBytes;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so muh @sampathpremarathna. I think that's what I need. Cheers for the help mate! :)